# Wrong weightpainting in object mod

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I've rig the "boots" to my characters using "transfer weight", everything is right in edit mode, but when i go back to object mode here is what i get :
[image]

[image]

Comment: A misalignment between the meshes (not at the same origin point or scale/rotation)? You should upload your file using this site http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or provide more information in the question itself.

Comment: Blend file added

Comment: OK, in pose mode, select all the bones and clear transforms (pose menu, then clear transforms and 'all'). The gap is because the armature was not in its rest pose position... a complement: you should redo the transfer in this rest pose position because of the gap you'll have in the feet (if not).